AKS Network Policy Manager vs Azure Cilium Network Policies
I am trying to implement network policies in Azure AKS cluster. upon reading docs I see Azure supports 3 policy engine

calico
Azure NPM
Azure CNI

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies#network-policy-options-in-aks
It also mentions that Cilium uses BPF vs Azure NPM using Linux Iptables where Cilium is more efficient.
I am wondering how cilium is better for network policies and when? My cluster is pretty small.
Can anyone tell how should I verify what kind of performance issues I can face with Azure NPM vs Cilium?

Cilium is generally considered to be more efficient than Azure Network Policy Manager for bigger cluster as it allows for more efficient packet processing and network policy enforcement directly in the Linux kernel. This can lead to improved performance, especially in larger clusters or when dealing with complex network policies. Since you have a small cluster, the performance differences may not be as pronounced, but Cilium's architecture can provide better observability of cluster traffic.

Cilium has it's own limitations- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-cni-powered-by-cilium#limitations
So does NPM- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies#limitations-of-azure-network-policy-manager
Azure Network Policy Manager (Azure npm) only supports up to 250 nodes.- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/best-practices-performance-scale-large#:~:text=Azure%20Network%20Policy%20Manager%20(Azure%20npm)%20only%20supports%20up%20to%20250%20nodes.

These document should give you clarity- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cni-with-cilium-most-scalable-and-performant-container-networking-in-the-cloud/
https://cilium.io/blog/2021/05/11/cni-benchmark/

@Arko I'd upvote these comments if they were answers :-)

Thank you @Arko, I have already the links you mentioned. I wish you had answered its would have accepted it as answer :)

@JatinMehrotra Will answer it.

Cilium can be more effective than Azure Network Policy Manager (NPM) for network policies due to its eBPF-based architecture, which allows it to operate within the Linux kernel.
Why Cilium Is Better for Network Policies?
Cilium uses eBPF enables network policy directly in the kernel, making it highly efficient for packet processing. As a result, it scales more effectively unlike Azure NPM, which relies on iptables which can slow down with a high number of rules, Cilium’s performance remains consistent even in clusters with complex policies even if the network policies grow in complexity or if the cluster size increases.
Even MS backs Cilium

What are the limitations of NPM vs Cilium?
Azure NPM supports clusters up to 250 nodes. Performance may degrade with many policies or heavy traffic.

vs
Cilium has slightly higher complexity during initial setup and requires familiarity with eBPF-based observability tools.
how should you verify what kind of performance issues you can face with Azure NPM vs Cilium?
You can run latency and throughput tests using monitor network configurations with Azure NPM or monitor metrics using Cilium plus few other tools are there like wrk or iperf to measure network latency, or even Azure Monitor.
